# What can be the problem when "eem_import_dir" is working properly?

Tags: r, list

eem_import_dir is supposed to "Reads Rdata and RDa files with one eemlist each. The eemlists are combined into one and returned." However, in my case, only one file is read at the time, and thus no combination is happening...

I don't expect any error in the function which is part of the staRdom package. I guess my limited R knowledge limits my understanding of the function and what could be wrong.

All files are the same class (eemlist) and in the same format. Tried changing the folder, filenames, etc. Can someone please help me understand the requirements of the function? Why is only one file read at the time and not all combined?

```
function (dir) 
{
  eem_files <- dir(dir, pattern = ".RData$|.RDa$", ignore.case = TRUE) %>% 
    paste0(dir, "/", .)
  for (file in eem_files) {
    file <- load(file)
    if (get(file) %>% class() == "eemlist") {
      if (exists("eem_list")) 
        eem_list <- eem_bind(eem_list, get(file))
      else eem_list <- get(file)
    }
    else {
      warning(paste0(file, " is no object of class eemlist!"))
    }
    NULL
  }
  eem_list
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try `eem_import_dir(getwd())`? From [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/staRdom/man/eem_import_dir.html) it looks like the function should do all the work, you'd just have to give it a directory. E.g. `eem_import_dir(getwd())` if you're already in that working directory, or `eem_import_dir("path/to/directory/with/eemlists)` if you're not

Comment: Can you run `getwd()` at tell us what it shows? (it will tell you what directory R is in). That is important because the function you're using will "Reads Rdata and RDa files with one eemlist each. The eemlists are combined into one and returned." - so the first thing to check is to make absolutely sure you're in the directory you mean to be in

Comment: Thank you for your comments @stevec I am 100% sure that the directory is correct since the files can be read, but only one at the time... and no combination is occuring. When running the function I specify the directory: eem_list <- eem_import_dir("C:/myfolder/")

Comment: Sounds like you're using it correctly. Are you able to run `dir("C:/myfolder/")` and make sure you see all the files you expected to be imported?

Comment: Yes, dir("C:/myfolder/") shows all files.

Comment: I've never used it before but it sounds like you're doing everything correctly, so I'm not too sure what could be the problem. if you think it's a bug you could create a new issue [here](https://github.com/MatthiasPucher/staRdom/issues) or reach out to the author (info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/staRdom/index.html))

Comment: Thank you @stevec I will go for your suggestion.

Comment: Hope you get it working. You could link to your question because the package author's first questions will probably be similar to mine (since the most likely causes is having the wrong directory). Good luck